# Multi-Dimensional Filtering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, filter

I would like to combine multiple type of filters with “or” and “and” logic at the same time. For example, i try to filter my Markers as in this example:
http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/ltgde

I have put multiple markers and i have created two functions that show or hide the markers.
The problem is that if i display markers from GroupA and then I select Markers with number 1, i will have all the markers with number 1. Or the goal is to have markers that are from GroupA and Number 1 at the same time.

Sorry, this is the simpest i could reduce it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multi-Filtering</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="multi_filters">
      <div class="Group"> 
        <a class="titre">Group</a></br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="GroupA" onclick="displayGroup('GroupA');" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" value="GroupB" onclick="displayGroup('GroupB');" checked>
      </div>
    </br>
      <div class="Number"> 
        <a class="titre">Number</a></br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Number1" onclick="displayNumber(1);" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Number2" onclick="displayNumber(2);" checked>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript:

```
    var markers =[];
    var locations = [
      ['GroupA','Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 2],
      ['GroupB','Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 2],
      ['GroupA','Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 1],
      ['GroupB','Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['GroupA','Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker, i; 
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map
      });
      marker.group= locations[i][0];
      marker.number = locations[i][4];
      markers.push(marker);   
    }

  function displayGroup(group) {
        var i;
       for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
         if (markers[i].group === group) {
          if(!(markers[i].getVisible(true))){markers[i].setVisible(true);}
           else{markers[i].setVisible(false);}
         }
       }
  }; 

  function displayNumber(number) {
        var i;
       for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
         if (markers[i].number === number) {
          if(!(markers[i].getVisible(true))){markers[i].setVisible(true);}
           else{markers[i].setVisible(false);}
         }
       }
  };
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Use checkboxes instead of click-buttons, then  you'll be able to choose multiple criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I put checkbox, but it seems that the problem seems to persist. For example, if you uncheck all the checkbox, the markers are visible.

Comment: of course you must refine your filtering-functions, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

Assuming a markup like this(click-listeners will be attached later):

```
<div id="multi_filters">
  <div class="Group"> 
    <a class="titre">Group</a></br>
    A<input type="checkbox" value="GroupA" data-prop="group" checked/>
    B<input type="checkbox" value="GroupB"  data-prop="group"/>
  </div>
</br>
  <div class="Number"> 
    <a class="titre">Number</a></br>
    1<input type="checkbox" value="1"  data-prop="number" checked/>
    2<input type="checkbox" value="2"  data-prop="number"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The attributes should be self-explaining, `data-prop` is the property-name stored for the markers, and `value` the value of the property to test against.

The following script creates based on the checked checkboxes Regular Expressions which will be stored in an object.

```
(function(boxes){

    for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;++i){
      //add click-listener for the checkboxes
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(boxes[i],'click',function(){
         var props={},box,prop,val,any,marker;
         for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;++i){
          box=boxes[i];
          prop=box.getAttribute('data-prop');
          val=box.value;

          if(box.checked){
            //variable to determine if there is any checkbox checked
            any=true;
            //populate an object with arrays
            //(key is the property-name)
            if(!props[prop]){
              props[prop]=[];
            }
            //push the value to the particular array
            props[prop].push(val);
          }
         }
         //create RegExp's from the arrays 
         for(var k in props){
            props[k]=new RegExp('^('+props[k].join('|')+')$');
         }
         //iterate over the markers
         for(var m=0;m<markers.length;++m){
          marker=markers[m];
          //no checkbox is checked, hide all markers
          if(!any){
            marker.setMap(null);
          }
          //there is a condition, check it
          else{
             inner:
            //iterate over the RegExp's
            for(var k in props){
              //if condition doesn't match hide marker and run next loop 
              if(!String(marker[k]).match(props[k])){
                marker.setMap(null);
                break inner;
              }
              //all RegExp's match, show the marker
              marker.setMap(map);
            }
          }
         }
      });
    }
    if(boxes.length){
      //trigger the event to apply the initial marker-state
      google.maps.event.trigger(boxes[0],'click',{})
    }
  })(document.querySelectorAll('input[data-prop]'));
```

For the given markup(group:GroupA and number:1 are checked) the resulting conditions e.g. would be:

```
{group:/^(GroupA)$/,number:/^(1)$/}
```

The script will run over these conditions and if any fails it hides the marker, otherwise it shows the marker.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QyMLg/

Comment: Thank you a lot Dr.Molle for you help. Your explanations are very clear and educational :)